# Control to present list of two-views pairs with flexible columns width

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I want to create a reusable control to present list of two-views pairs. I want to be able to addd different number of such pairs programatically. Views in first column should be aligned to start and views in second column should be aligned to end. For example let's assume we want to present pairs label and value so we want something like this:

```
Text1    1
Text2   14
Text3  423
```

but there is one important thing. These columns width shouldn't be fixed. If at least one text is longer, the whole column should be wider. So for example:

```
Text1  123456
Text2      12
Text3    1234
Text4       1
```

or

```
Text1                 123
Text2Text2             12
Text3Text3Text3Text3  123
Text4                   1
```

Of course there is a maximum space for this control so if there is no enough space second column should has higher priority and texts in first column should be broken into more lines. First column shouldn't be totally squeeze so should has some minimum width (percentage) and if text in second column is still too long then text in second column should be broken into more lines too. If some text is multiline then text in other column should be centered verticaly to this text.

I've tried to do this using GridLayout or using two vertical LinearLayout inside ConstraintLayout or using only ConstraintLayout and adding views and constraints to it. Nothing works as I expected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    private ConstraintLayout _constraintLayout;
    private Dictionary<object, Tuple<View, View>> _objectWithViews;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        _constraintLayout = FindViewById<ConstraintLayout>(Resource.Id.constraintLayout);
        _objectWithViews = new Dictionary<object, Tuple<View, View>>();

        var items = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
        {
            Tuple.Create("Text1", "10"),
            Tuple.Create("Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2", "123122124123535"),
            Tuple.Create("Text3Text3Text3", "230"),
            Tuple.Create("Text4Text4Text4Text4", "10"),
            Tuple.Create("Text5Text5", "123450")
        };

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            View titleView = GetTextView(item.Item1);
            View valueView = GetTextView(item.Item2);

            titleView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Beige);
            valueView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Red);

            AddViews(titleView, valueView);
            _objectWithViews.Add(item, Tuple.Create(titleView, valueView));
        }
    }

    private void AddViews(View view1, View view2)
    {
        var constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();

        constraintSet.Clone(_constraintLayout);

        view1.Id = View.GenerateViewId();
        view2.Id = View.GenerateViewId();

        _constraintLayout.AddView(view1);
        _constraintLayout.AddView(view2);

        constraintSet.ConstrainWidth(view1.Id, ConstraintSet.MatchConstraint);
        constraintSet.ConstrainHeight(view1.Id, ConstraintSet.WrapContent);

        constraintSet.ConstrainWidth(view2.Id, ConstraintSet.WrapContent);
        constraintSet.ConstrainHeight(view2.Id, ConstraintSet.WrapContent);

        // This way i tried to set max second column width to not totally squeeze first column but it also doesn't work
        /*constraintSet.ConstrainMaxWidth(view2.Id, ConstraintSet.MatchConstraintWrap);
        constraintSet.ConstrainPercentWidth(view2.Id, 0.6f);*/

        constraintSet.Connect(view1.Id, ConstraintSet.Left, ConstraintSet.ParentId, ConstraintSet.Left);
        constraintSet.Connect(view2.Id, ConstraintSet.Right, ConstraintSet.ParentId, ConstraintSet.Right);
        constraintSet.Connect(view1.Id, ConstraintSet.Right, view2.Id, ConstraintSet.Left);
        constraintSet.Connect(view2.Id, ConstraintSet.Left, view1.Id, ConstraintSet.Right);

        constraintSet.CreateHorizontalChain(ConstraintSet.ParentId, ConstraintSet.Left, ConstraintSet.ParentId,
            ConstraintSet.Right, new[] { view1.Id, view2.Id }, null, ConstraintSet.ChainPacked);

        if (!_objectWithViews.Any())
        {
            constraintSet.Connect(view1.Id, ConstraintSet.Top, ConstraintSet.ParentId, ConstraintSet.Top);
            constraintSet.Connect(view2.Id, ConstraintSet.Top, ConstraintSet.ParentId, ConstraintSet.Top);
        }
        else
        {
            var previousViews = _objectWithViews.Last().Value;

            constraintSet.Connect(view1.Id, ConstraintSet.Top, previousViews.Item1.Id, ConstraintSet.Bottom);
            constraintSet.Connect(view2.Id, ConstraintSet.Top, view1.Id, ConstraintSet.Top);
            constraintSet.Connect(view2.Id, ConstraintSet.Bottom, view1.Id, ConstraintSet.Bottom);
        }

        constraintSet.ApplyTo(_constraintLayout);
    }

    private TextView GetTextView(string text)
    {
        var titleView = new TextView(this)
        {
            Text = text,
        };

        titleView.SetSingleLine(false);
        titleView.SetMaxLines(5);

        return titleView;
    }
}
```

Result

[image: Result]

Comment: can you tell me why using constraint_layout and chaining the two textviews together didn't work?

Comment: I've updated my post, now you can see one of my solution using constraint layout as you mentioned. I've tried use chains, use barriers, set widths to wrap_conten, match_parents, match_constraint, use different chain style but nothing works... Do you know what should I change to make it works?

Comment: Using this layout your textviews still overlap?

Comment: I've added screenshot. First of all there is no one border between columns. All rows should have same width and there shouldn't be such big space between columns. Second column should be next to first one and empty space should be on the right side of second column.

Comment: For the space issue, you need to makr thr chainstyle packed, for the rows width one , do you mean that in the screenshot the second row should be divided into 5 rows ? so that its width equals the first's

Comment: No, in this case there is no need to break any line because there is enough space. Columns width should depends on the longest text in column. I want every single textview in the same column to have the same width but on screenshot you can see that in every row first textview has different width (background color).

Comment: I see now, i don't know if it's the most efficient way it will cost running time but you may declare an int paramter in the adapter class and then call view tree observer on the textview in onBindViewHolder method so you set the int paramter to the longest textview and then you make this value the value of the textview ( don't forget to call notifySetChanged)

Comment: I have another more efficient idea but i fail implementing it each time  if you have no problem that the second column stays in the parent end try using barriers or guide lines  , set it in the second column start, then constraint the end of the first column to this guideline/barrier and make its width match_constraint

Comment: I know it can be done using barriers, I've tried such solution as well. I have one main problem every time in every approach. When I set columns width to match_constraint/0dp whole control has maximum width, so there is never space on the right side of second column. But when I set columns width to wrap content to avoid such behaviour then I have space on right side but when one text is too long then part of the control is out of the screen.

Comment: Try my first solution, if you don't know what is view tree it's to make sure you get the width after the view is rendered